# Remove tint color but keep font color UISegmentedControl

Tags: uisegmentedcontrol, uicolor, ios11, uifont, swift4

I would like to remove the selected color from my `UISegmetedControl`.  I know `tintColor` can do this but that also removes the font color with it. Also using `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` will remove both.

Side note I made a `UIView` and placed it above the selected segment to show selected state.  I thought this would look better.  Trying to branch out and make my own custom controls.

```
public let topLine = UIView()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.removeBorders()
    setFont()
    addTopLine()
}

func setFont() {
    let font = UIFont(name: FontTypes.avenirNextUltraLight, size: 22.0)!
    let textColor = UIColor.MyColors.flatWhite
    let attribute = [kCTFontAttributeName:font]
    self.setTitleTextAttributes(attribute, for: .normal)
}

func addTopLine() {
    topLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.MyColors.flatWhite
    let frame = CGRect(x: 7,
                       y: -5,
                       width: Int(self.frame.size.width)/2,
                       height: 2)
    topLine.frame = frame
    self.addSubview(topLine)
}

struct FontTypes {
     static let avenirNextRegular = "AvenirNext-Regular"
     static let avenirLight = "Avenir-Light"
     static let avenirNextUltraLight = "AvenirNext-UltraLight"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TintColor is attach with

- Background colour of Selected segment,
- Text color of Unselected segment and
- Border colour of UISegmentedControl.

So, if you going to change tintColor to white, then background colour and tint color Both are gone.

You need to set Selected/Unselected text attribute like below:

```
mySegment.tintColor = .white

let selectedAtrribute = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.red, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
mySegment.setTitleTextAttributes(selectedAtrribute as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.selected)

let unselected = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black, NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)]
mySegment.setTitleTextAttributes(unselected as [NSObject : AnyObject], for: UIControlState.normal)
```